# Strange Array behavior using push and splice

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

I have a page full of mc_card's and want the user to choose which ones to add to their deck.

click a card and cardChosen = true for that card;

click again and cardChosen = false;

This works fine.

Upon choosing a card the frame number is stored in an array. Each card is on a separate frame and there are no duplicates.

```
Main.cardArray.push(this.currentFrame);
```

Upon clicking it again, I want to remove that frame number from the array:

```
Main.cardArray.splice(this.currentFrame, 1);
```

After I splice the array, I trace it, and I'm getting weird results. Sometimes it works like I would expect, but then it removes the wrong numbers and sometimes doesnt remove them at all.

Comment: I think I solved this on my own by adding indexOf(this.currentFrame) But I am still confused as to why the first method didn't work.

Comment: A little bit of context in the form of compilable code (only the relevant part!) would be useful. More on this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And by the way, what programming language do you refer to?

Comment: the first argument is the index at which to remove the object. You are confusing yourself because you store numbers and confuse them with indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

splice() works in another way, that you try to use.
Here is statement:

```
splice(startIndex:int, deleteCount:uint, ... values):Array
```

So, first arg - start index in array to delete, and second arg - how much elements must be deleted from the start index.